# Appium-inspector cannot load certain pages within the app

Tags: java, android, appium

This is a first (& weird) situation for me.  I am testing an eCommerce app using the latest of Appium - Java-client (5.0.0-BETA8) and when I get to a certain page within the app, Appium-Inspector will just hang and the spinner will keep spinning attempting to load.  I've tried downgrading the client to (4.1.2) - still did not work.

Steps:
1. Open the app to the main homepage - Inspector works fine and loads the DOM
2. Add an item to a cart - Inspector loads the page fine and am able to inspect the elements.
3. Proceed to checkout page (where beginning to enter the billing information), Inspector cannot load the page & displays a spinner that keeps spinning and spinning and spinning. But when I go back to a non-checkout page, then Inspector works fine.

When I run the test and gets to the checkout page, it cannot find the particular element(s), acting similarly to what inspector is doing.  And this is against an Android simulator.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I've found the UIAutomator to be finicky.  Try getting to the page you want first, then load the UIAutomator and take the snapshot on that page first.  Make sure you have a fresh start of the Appium server, too.  It's often the server that causes the automator to lock up.

Comment: Ok, let me give it a try - thank you